# Linq Simple query error

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a simple query in LINQ. In fact it is my first query in Linq. How the query is interpreted by compiler confused me. *My query is not giving any result*.

My Linq Query:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(("connection string")))
{
    var notif_sched_data = from sched  in db.NOTIF_SCHEDs
                           join  recip in db.NOTIF_RECIPs
                           on sched.NOTIF_RECIP_ID equals recip.NOTIF_RECIP_ID
                           select sched.NOTIF_RPT_ID;
}
```

which is interpreted by compiler as

```
SELECT [t0].[NOTIF_RPT_ID]
FROM [dbo].[NOTIF_SCHED] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[NOTIF_RECIP] AS [t1] ON [t0].[NOTIF_RECIP_ID] = [t1].[NOTIF_RECIP_ID]
```

and it gives no row as output. However,the SQL which is correctly working is :

```
select [NOTIF_SCHED].[NOTIF_RPT_ID] 
from [NOTIF_SCHED] 
INNER JOIN [NOTIF_RECIP] on [NOTIF_RECIP].[NOTIF_RECIP_ID]=[NOTIF_SCHED].[NOTIF_RECIP_ID].
```

Can somebody tell me what I need to change?
if i change the value around **equals**,it gives error as **value is not in the right scope.**

Comment: how it's interpreted into SQL isn't necessarily relevant. Does the query return the data you want? if so, it's working fine and you don't need to inspect the SQL it generates.

Comment: NO it gives no value(blank) as output.I just added how it is being interpreted so as to provide additional information

Comment: Are you sure EF is connecting to the same database you ran the SQL query on?  I suggest checking the connection string.

Comment: Unless my eyes betray me, which is quite possible because lots of square brackets and capitalization does that to my eyes, those two SQL queries are functionally identical.

Comment: Did you try calling "ToList" to actually execute the query?

Comment: Posting some sample data how it exists in the database may give some insight as well. From my initial look it seems like it would work. Unless the connection to SQL is not correct.

Comment: just try the generated sql query if it works,,, then check ur sql connection

Comment: @Styxxy ToList doesn't cause the query to execute.  It changes the data structure from a IQueryable to a List

Comment: i will provide some sample data in a minute.Thanks all

Comment: I am extremely sorry to waste all your time.I am new to LINQ.The problem is that generated sql have  "[dbo].[NOTIF_SCHED]" which should be simple notif_sched as it is table not database. I Tried db.gettable<notif_sched> but still same .Compiler is adding  [dbo] before table name.What I am missing? I edited the code above.

Comment: `dbo.[NOTIF_SCHED]` is a valid way to reference a table. `dbo` is merely the schema where it lives. You could very well define another schema to keep some tables that are unrelated to those in `dbo` and would reference them as `otherSchema.[TableName]`

Comment: Please confirm that 1) you are connecting to the same database in your code as you are when you manually run the query, and 2) you are forcing the query to execute. Take the result (`notif_sched_data`) and do a `.ToList()` on it to make the query execute right then.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop I am connecting to same database  but i am not doing anything like .ToList() instead i am using a foreach loop for that. Also,If i execute the querry  manually after removing 'dbo' ,it is working fine

Comment: can somebody please help me finding a way so that dbo doesn`t get added as without that,query is working fine.

Comment: @vish1990 you probably need to change your connection string.  Is your connection string connecting as the same user as you are when you are running the query?

Comment: @Hogan Thanks for your reply Sir but i am using same connection string and as the same User when I am running the query. I tried with other queries also.Adding dbo before table name doesn`t work and gives 0 rows as output

Comment: you are very welcome noble knight but please inform me why the dbo schema prefix does not work if both connections have the same rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not materializing the query in anyway. the query will return you IQueryable of what you are selecting there. To get the query actually executed to the database you need to materialize the results with methods like .Count(), .FirstOrDefault(), .Tolist(), etc...

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext(("connection string")))
{
    var query = (from sched  in db.NOTIF_SCHEDs
               join  recip in db.NOTIF_RECIPs
               on sched.NOTIF_RECIP_ID equals recip.NOTIF_RECIP_ID
               select sched.NOTIF_RPT_ID);

    var count = query.Count();

    var list = query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. Actually query was correct. The problem was in the class file where we convert sql objects in OOPS objects.

Answer (score -2):

i think the problem is for the last line.you should create a new anonymous type.so changing the last line to this may solve the problem :

```
select new { sched.NOTIF_RPT_ID };
```

also you can create a class like this one and set your values to an object of the class

```
public class data
{
 public int id {get;set}
 public somthing somthing {get;set}
...
}
```

now simply :

```
select new { id = sched.NOTIF_RPT_ID , something = x , ... };
```

Comment: If I am correct, the anonymous type should be automatically created.

Comment: @kyurthich refer to this  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) anonymous types should be create like this

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about VB it seems.

Comment: I don't know that you need an anonymous type. Selecting the value directly from the entity should still work just fine.

Comment: as i know proper approach to select data in linq is like this.what's wrong with annonymous type? @Andy_Vulhop
using second approach is really strait-forward for making new object of a class though.

Comment: @SaeidBn Again, I don't think you need an anonymous type here. The question asker only pulled 1 value off of the table. Wrapping that in an object with one property is pointless.

Comment: i just show that it can be done for more than one object! if you see i show more than one property not one ,anyway for one just use the new and the item to catch.nothing wired here @Andy_Vulhop

Comment: This isn't actually addressing the problem raised.